# Create a Key and save the .pem file using Terraform (Windows/AWS)

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a *EC2* server and after this server is created, run a few lines of code to install *Nginx*.

For this, I need to create first the key pair, save it in a `.pem` file and then access the remote server using the provisioner `"remote-exec"`.

The first problem I find is that the `.pem` file is not being created because of this (I think):

`aws_key_pair.generated_key (local-exec): (output suppressed due to sensitive value in config)`

Is there any way to avoid this problem and create a `.pem` file using *Terraform* in Windows?

This is the code I have been using.

`````
    region = "us-east-1"
}

variable "key_name" {
    default = "terraform"
}

resource "tls_private_key" "example" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "generated_key" {
  key_name   = var.key_name
  public_key = tls_private_key.example.public_key_openssh

  provisioner "local-exec" { # Create a "terraform.pem" to your computer!!
    command = "echo '${tls_private_key.example.private_key_pem}' > ./${aws_key_pair.generated_key.key_name}.pem"
  }

}

data "aws_ami" "app_ami" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["amazon"]

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-hvm*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "myec2" {
    ami = data.aws_ami.app_ami.id
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    key_name = aws_key_pair.generated_key.key_name

    connection {
        type = "ssh"
        user = "ec2-user"
        #password = var.root_password
        private_key = file("./${aws_key_pair.generated_key.key_name}.pem")
        host = self.public_ip
    }

    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
            "sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y nginx1",
            "sudo systemctl start nginx"
        ]
    }

}

output "private_key" {
        value     = tls_private_key.example.private_key_pem
        sensitive = true
}````
`````

Comment: provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-1"
}

Answer (score 0):

This is typically not recommended as I've come across numerous people who have been misguided in their attempts to perform the very same action.

```
resource "tls_private_key" "private-key" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "my-key-pair" {
  key_name   = "YourKey"
  public_key = tls_private_key.private-key.public_key_openssh
}

resource "local_file" "ssh_key" {
  filename = "${aws_key_pair.my-key-pair.key_name}.pem"
  content = tls_private_key.private-key.private_key_pem
}
```

You can write the to a "local_file" with using `tls_private_key` and `tls_public_key` and their provider functions.